# Python - Write RTL File With Brackets At The End Of The Line

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a text file with Hebrew characters, when I use write brackets or any other sign the
the result is showing in the wrong direction:
כתיבת קובץ בשפה (עברית)

I am using codecs.open :

```
outfile = codecs.open(fileName+'.txt', encoding="iso-8859-8", mode='w+')        
outfile.write("עברית");
```

Is there a way to set direction for writing to a text file ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible to define this with a text document created with notepad or something like that? If it is, save the file manually and read the file in python. Then just copy what you get.

Comment: Can you show an erroneous example?

Comment: Please show us an example of a Python program that does the wrong thing, the output it gives us, and the output that would be correct.

Comment: Please specify exactly what version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to give you a good answer, but here are a couple of guesses that might help you a little bit.

I think you should be using Python 3.x, because Unicode is really well-integrated.  If you are using Python 2, your call to `outfile.write()` is getting a string of bytes, and I'm not sure whether that string will be correct.  Maybe your text editor is writing UTF-8 in your source file?  If it's Python 2.x, you might be sending UTF-8 to be written as ISO-8859-8, and maybe it's not right.

If your source file is UTF-8 and you are using Python 3, then I think your program should be doing what you expect.

If your source file is ISO-8859-8, and you are using Python 2, then I'm still not sure what will happen.  If your source file is ISO-8859-8, you might want to try just using `open()` instead of `codecs.open()` and that might do the right thing.

If you put additional information that might help me figure this out, please put a comment or question under this answer, and StackOverflow will tell me to look here again.

Really, I think the best thing to do is use UTF-8 for your source code files and use Python 3.